# Is it possible to take input from javascript alert()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take the input from user from the javascript and i am calling that function

```
body onload="function()"
```

now what i want is i want to take the user name when some user visits the home page.
so can i do this using alert or any other method is there?

pls help me..

here is what i am using.

```
function inpt()
{
alert(<input type="text" name="username" value="">);
}
```

but this is not giving any alert().

Comment: Try Javascript prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Javascript prompt box as shown below.

```
function getName(){
    var person=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
    if (person!=null && person!="")
      {
            //do whatever with the name
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript `alert` will take text as its parameter not html.

You are looking for `prompt`:

```
var username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Your name");
```

Answer (score 2):

see this example from w3schools , means anything to you ??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;

var person=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");

if (person!=null)
  {
  x="Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.prompt()`

For more information on `prompt()`, see

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `window.prompt();`  to get input using javascript

```
function firstName(){
   var name =  window.prompt("First Name ","Yousuf Umar");
   document.getElementById("firstName").value=name;

}


   <input type="text" name="name" id="fistName" onclick="firstName();">
```